# Issue with Sextante r.map calculator and modeler

Tags: grass-gis, raster-calculator, sextante

I am trying to build a model with Sextante modeler and the r.mapcalculator algorithm but when I run the model I get the error message:

```
‘Could not load layer: ‘….’Check sextant log to look for errors in algorithm execution.’
```

The Sextant Log reads:

```
sextante.runalg("modeler:ndsi.","H:/NDSI/MODIS/20120607_SurfaceReflectance
   /0607_Processed Images/0607_b4_warp","H:/NDSI/MODIS/20120607_SurfaceReflectance
      /0607_Processed Images/0607_band6_warp","H:/NDSI/MODIS/test/NDSI")
```

The algorithm I have put into r.mapcalculator is a basic algorithm to calculate NDSI for snowcover analysis:

```
e.g. (amap-bmap)/(amap+bmap)

amap = band 4

bmap= band 6
```

I have tried on different computers as well as only using the r.mapcalculator through the Sextante Toolbox. Is there a different calculator I can use in my model? Is there a different way I should write out my algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the GRASS logging (in the SEXTANTE configuration dialog, under GRASS), and then have a look at the log, but in the "Info" branch. You should have there a "GRASS console output" entry. That will tell you more about what is happening when you call grass.

Post it here so we can help you with it.