# How do I fix this QGIS sextante error? NameError: name 'sextante' is not defined

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sextante-qgis-plugin

A colleague of mine posted [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48681/issue-with-sextante-r-map-calculator-and-modeler) the other day. We haven't got any nibbles yet and I wanted to elaborate on the issue.

We are having trouble running the r.mapcalculator function and receive the error below

[image]

I have gone into the file "HistoryDialog.py" and changed a reference to Sextante on line 101 to 'sextante' (original text shown below). I think I am clutching at straws here, because after this change I receive another error altogether.

[image]

A good googling returned nothing related to the 'sextante is not defined error'. Surely someone else has come across this before. Also for us it is happening on Ubuntu and Windows. We installed the latest dev version through Osgeo4w installer but no luck!!

Comment: Sextante is a work in progress. For feedback on potential bugs and weirdnesses, I recommend to get developer support on the QGIS mailing list.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which QGIS list would I post this to? QGIS-trac?